# nginx try_files, pushState, and 404

Tags: nginx, pushstate

I'm trying to configure nginx to work with a pushState-enabled app. I've got it mostly working, but what I'm missing is getting a 404 returned on non-existent documents. How can I achieve this? Relevant part of my nginx.conf:

```
location / {
  root /foo;
  index index.html;
  try_files $uri /index.html;
}
```

I've tried `try_files $uri /index.html =404;`, but that didn't work, obviously, because `index.html` exists.

I've also tried...

```
if (!-e $request_filename) {
  return 404;
}
```

...in the `server` and `location` block. Neither worked.

Comment: If you want 404, what for you use `try_files`?

Comment: I'm using pushState. So, for example, a request to `/foo` should be redirected through `/index.html` to boot up the application, but **only** if `foo.html` exists on disk.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If file exists, redirect to index.html. Otherwise return 404.

```
location = /index.html {}

location / {
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
        return 404;
    }
    rewrite ^/(.*) /index.html redirect;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full configuration?